# SQLServer Error: 18546 - SQLState 28000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, odbc, windows-server-2008-r2, hyperion

I have a 3-level application running. WebServer IIS7.5 and SQLServer 2008 R2 Express Database and OS WinServer 2008 WebEdition.

When I try to connect via ODBC from a PC on the network have this error.

[image]

Remote connections with MSSM (Microsoft SqlServer Managemet Studio) work properly.
I want to use this ODBC to connect Hyperion to SQLServer

Can you help me?

Comment: do you have enable sa account and enable mix authentication mode . if local sqlserver can connection check your firewall .

Comment: @King Jk Mixed authemtication mode is enable. The firewall is disabled by excluding it from the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve to enable TCP/IP service in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

[image]

After this , if problem persist disable firewall on private/domestic net and try again.