# Microsoft SQL Server login. Connection failed: SQL state 28000

Tags: vba, sql-server-2012, ms-access-2013

We're quite very new into this space...

So, we've got a few linked tables in MS-Access:

[image: Linked tables in MS-Access]

When hovered, they've this detail in the tooltip:

> ODBC:DSN=EHSDB_Replica;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2013;DATABASE=EHSDB_Replica;TABLE=dbo.Accident

Seems like, we've got the DNS configured correctly:

[image: DSN configuration]

When tested, the DSN is also failing:

[image: Test failed]

Whenever we try to open the tables, it throws the below error:

> Login failed for user

[image]

We already tried the following:

- [ODBC Data Source SQL Server Connection - Login Failed For User](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39636)
- [Error message when you try to authenticate an ODBC connection to your SQL Server 2005 or 2008 SQL Instance by using the ‘sa’ credentials: "Login failed for ‘sa’.”](http://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2121736)
- [SQLServer Error: 18546 - SQLState 28000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26774688/7172091)

Comment: Does the user `CIS\ZAnsari` exist on the SQL Server? If you click "Test Data Source", does that work?

Comment: @Andre It works https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCqjY.png. Can you add this to the question? I have got the privilege issues

Comment: I can, but in that image it says "Client version 09" and in your question it is "Client version 11". So it seems to be a different DSN?

Comment: @Andre No, sorry I'm wrong. `Test Data Source` is failing. Please add [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgoIi.png)

Comment: Secret: you can do it yourself, just add the code manually to your question. E.g. `![Test failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgoIi.png)`